# What is UUID and CoreBluetooth?

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I don't understand about UUID SERVICE! can I find where that?
e.g.
[image]

[image]

Comment: You should post code, not screen shots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service and characteristic UUIDs are defined by your peripheral.

There are some well-known services and characteristics defined by the [Bluetooth SIG](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services).  These are typically abbreviated to 4 hex digits since they come from a common UUID range.

Peripherals can use any UUID they want for other services and characteristics.

The UUIDs in your question appear to be private values; You need to refer to the peripheral or manufacturer documentation for information on those.

Comment: can i find UUID where? or Could i create it my self?